# Apple Mail multiple chimes after mail arrives

Tags: email, notifications

I'm running Mail on High Sierra and there is an audible tone or chime when the mail arrives, then there is another chime a minute or so later, then more chimes when there is no new arrivals (perhaps its announcing the last mail for the third/forth/fifth time, each about a minute apart). Its been the case for a long time but I can't seem to locate where the chimes are being generated.

I don't know where these chimes are controlled. I know there is a notifications option in mail filters, but there are none set for all incoming mail (which is what is setting it off) and I've turned off Play sound for notifications inside the Notification sys pref for mail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check your rules, they can play sounds - & they sometimes get confused. I have one that plays incoming mail for outgoing, if it is sent to one specific folder...

Comment: Thanks but I've already done that as it was the first place I looked. I think I've found the issue - Mail has suddenly decided to (re)download a thousand emails for some reason.